# How do i create a validation function that makes the user input not repeat?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation

I need help in making a validation function to help me get an error output when the user input is repeated.

this is just a part of the code that i am doing and i just need help in making a validation function.

```
Color_ID_List=[]
maxColorList=15
while len(Color_ID_List)<maxColorList:
    b=input("Enter New color: ")
    c=int(input("Enter ID: "))
    d=input("Enter type of color: ")
    print("The ID of", b, "is", c,"and the type of color is",d)
    Color_ID_List.append(b)
    Color_ID_List.append(c)
    Color_ID_List.append(d)

print("")
print("")
print("The following colors and ID has been added")
print(Color_ID_List)
```

Comment: make a `set()` of ids and compare against it - disallow same inputs...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `in` statement. This would look something like this:

```
def validationFunction(input, list):
  if input in list:
    return False
  else:
    return True
```

When this function returns `True`, the input is already in the list.